# How do I make Mix Blend Mode ignore certain backgrounds?

Tags: css

Please take a look at the image below:

[image]

Imagine the blue rectangle at the bottom, with mix-blend-mode: difference, is slowly moving up towards the top. I would like it to ignore the red stripe and stay blue when crossing it, but use the mix-blend-mode for when it is on the green stripe. How would I go about doing this?

Comment: I would post the [mcve] that you have right now

Answer (score 0):

You can put the mix-blend-mode on the rectangle where you want the blue rectangle to change and leave it off the one that is not to change the blue rectangle.

Here's a simple example:

```html
<style>
  .green {
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
    background: lime;
    mix-blend-mode: difference;
  }
  
  .red {
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
    background: red;
  }
  
  .blue {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: blue;
    animation: move 5s infinite linear;
    osition: absolute;
  }
  
  @keyframes move {
    0% {
      margin-top: 0px;
    }
    100% {
      margin-top: -300px;
    }
  }
</style>
<div class="green"></div>
<div class="red"></div>
<div class="blue"></div>
```